# Is this Kippa clip muktzeh?

Tags: halacha, clothing, muktzeh, kippa-yarmulka

I got [this really cool kippa clip](http://odditymall.com/leatherdos-is-a-hair-clip-multi-tool). I'm wondering, is it muktzeh?

Comment: Ze'ev, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! You could make this question more answerable if you [edit] in more information about this clip, especially the aspects of it that make you wonder whether it is muktzeh.

Comment: It's tzorech gufo, I would thikn.

Comment: .... do you really want to put something in your hair (and yarmulke!) that you just used to fasten an oily nut?  Or shred carrots?  Just saying, "melachah" is not really the primary purpose of this object.

Answer (score 2):

A **KLI** is not muktza unless oser bianoo, muktza Bain hashmoshois, muktsa machmas mitsva, or muktsa machmas hsoroin kis

But if the KLI is set for use that is forbidden on Shabos you can only move it to use it or for its place but not to save it from harm

This KLI seems to fall in the category of a KLI used for permitted things, that is only forbidden to be moved without reason

Shulchan aruch harav orach Chaim 308.21 (also see mogain Avrohom 308.9)

> כלי שמלאכתו לאיסור ולהיתר מותר לטלטלו אף לצורך הכלי עצמו כדין כלי שמלאכתו להיתר הואיל והוא מיוחד ג"כ למלאכת היתר:

My translation

> a KLI that is used for forbidden and for permitted is allowed to be moved for it (the KLI) itself as the law by a KLI that is used for permitted, since it is also set for a permitted act

Answer (score 0):

[Rav Neustadt](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5763/shemos.html) distinguishes between

> a) severe (chamur) muktzeh - items which are "set apart" before
>   Shabbos because they will definitely not be used on Shabbos.
>
> and b) light (kal) muktzeh - items which are set apart because they
>   are normally used for activities which are prohibited on Shabbos, but
>   may, on occasion, be used for a permitted Shabbos activity, e.g.,
>   scissors.
>
> Severe muktzeh may never(1) be moved in a normal, straightforward
>   manner(2), while light muktzeh may be moved in either of the following
>   cases: a) if the muktzeh item is needed in order to perform a
>   permissible activity, or b) if the place which the muktzeh item
>   occupies is needed in order to perform a permissible activity.
>
> A hammer, a typical light muktzeh, may be used in order to crack nuts.
>   A sewing needle, another light muktzeh, may be used to remove a
>   splinter from one's finger. Since nut-cracking and splinter removal
>   are permitted activities, a light muktzeh item may be used. [The
>   poskim(3) note, however, that light muktzeh should only be employed
>   when no other suitable item is readily available. Therefore, if a
>   nutcracker and a hammer are equally accessible, the nutcracker should
>   be used. There is no need, however, to borrow a nutcracker if a hammer
>   is available.]

Now the hairclip multi tool consists of various implements some of which if they were separate implements would be categorised as light muktzeh but may not have the same uses in this hairclip:

- screw-drivers (3), (mentioned as [light muktzeh](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5763/shemos.html))
- a wrench, (can be moved [for itself or its place](http://www.toraschaimdallas.org/wp-content/files/Muktza.pdf) and so in principle is light muktzeh)
- a trolley coin, (a coin is [severe muktzeh](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9jS56-VAXsMC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=muktzeh+coin&source=bl&ots=jhmabsia0M&sig=8hQ0xkAcXbzHEagS_CEbZQaTbSA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KzqXVNCDDZDgaKWXgcAK&ved=0CEkQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=muktzeh%20coin&f=false) – a trolley coin may be too.
- a ruler, (light muktzeh, Rav Neustadt)
- and a cutting edge (if it could be used for permitted cutting purposes, it would not be muktzeh at all)

So, the hairclip is muktzeh. At least one of the uses is clearly “severe muktzeh” in the formulation of Rabbi Neustadt.